# Twilio Fax API - how to get the failure reason for failed fax send

Tags: api, twilio, fax

Hi all (especially Twilio evangelists out there)

I've connected my EMR app to Twilio in order to send faxes, and it works reasonably well, however there's one big problem I'm running into. Some faxes fail to send, and I can't find the reason for it. If the line is busy, or if there's no answer, Twilio marks the fax instances accordingly, and I can attempt a retry or whatever. But in some circumstances I do not understand, a sent fax immediately comes back as Failed through the webHook. So it gets "queued", but the first message I receive from the webHook is FAILED - no additional data whatsoever.

I've tried checking the developer tools Debugger, but there nothing there - it's 100% blank (checked last 30 days). I know from my test account that I should find the failure reason there, if there's something wrong with my implementation (e.g., if Twilio can't fetch my PDF, or I don't provide the "from" number, etc). But on production account, it's empty.

Faxes that I send to myself (Toshiba multifunction) work just fine, report busy when busy, etc. But the faxes sent to other companies fail, though I'm quite sure the numbers are OK. I was wondering if anybody can make a list of the possible reasons for a fax to fail? And I was also wondering why Twilio doesn't send more details on Failed faxes, it would be very helpful to know what happened from my logs...

Thanks,
Vic

Comment: I've learned something new - it may help someone out there - my problem may have something to do with QUALITY parameter. I've defaulted it to "superfine" since my client was not satisfied with "fine", and on one test send to the fax that failed earlier, we tested "superfine" and got Failed, then repeated with "Fine" and got Delivered. I'll try to make a routine to make another attempt with lower quality and if that solves all problems then I know at least one answer to my question.

Comment: I recommend using a tool like Postman to test your Post Request, it might provide better error reporting so that you get a better sense of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick that works well, at least when you're just figuring it out.  Instead of taking the time to set up a statusCallback URL to handle the error, use an invalid url.  This will cause an "Error - 11200 HTTP retrieval failure" in the Twilio debugger, which will include the POST request parameters, including any ErrorMessage.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I'm calling the APIs from a desktop app, so didn't want to spin up a webservice just to troubleshoot during development.  This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

The [statusCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/fax/rest/faxes#list-post-optional-parameters) parameter makes as request to a URL when the status of the fax changes and includes [parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/fax/rest/faxes#fax-status-callback) like Status, ErrorCode and ErrorReason.

```
curl 'https://fax.twilio.com/v1/Faxes' \
    -X POST \
    -d 'To=%2B15558675309'  \
    -d 'From=%2B15017250604'  \
    -d 'MediaUrl=https://www.twilio.com/docs/documents/25/justthefaxmaam.pdf' \
    -d 'StatusCallback=https://example.com/statusUpdates' \
    -u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token
```

Twilio Fax is still in beta but I know that adding the ability to display fax logs in the Twilio Console is planned.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Devin. I noticed the statusCallback parameter and applied it already, this is how I get the FAILED status. The problem is, I don't have a clue WHY it has failed so I can do something about it :) Would you happen to know any address to contact someone from Twilio team working directly on this? I may have an idea or two for them... I know they're serious about their business so I'd like to help.

Comment: I'd suggest shooting an email to our support team help@twilio.com with some of the fax sids for the failed faxes.  They are in a much better position to dig into the details and see if they can tell why the faxes are failing.